# Loading Issues With Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, preloader

I'm having a few issues with masonry, just wondering if anyone can help with any of them

1) Masonry doesn't kick in until all images are loaded and they're all stuck on the top-left of page until that's done
2) Images visibly load slowly, would love if they wouldn't display until fully loaded through some kind of pre-loader 
3) The images are always positioned in a funny way on first load, but every refresh after that they are placed correctly

you can see the work in progress here, a little background, the images are meant to be loaded with random sizes, positioning and order on every load http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/oddfuture/

Answer (score 4):

You are using the images loaded plugin which is delaying the masonry plugin init. What you could do is:

Hide the content using css:

```
#container {display:none}
```

Show the images once they have been loaded and apply masonry:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){

  $container.show();

  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.photo'
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @darshanags
I made the recommended changes but everything stays hidden and never comes back into display. What exactly is meant to be in the itemSelector for '.box' is not used in my site

Comment: I don't know how this site works haha does @darshanags actually even tag someone?

Comment: lol. stay calm, I was on the road. the .box was an example which you needed to change to your selector which is .photo. i've updated the example code.

Comment: haha sorry I was just trying to figure out how this worked for future reference haha, my bad
but this still keeps everything hidden, hmm...

Comment: well, you need to clean up your page a bit. You are currently loading multiple jQuery versions and you have multiple script tags in your page which you need to combine and clean any duplicate code that comes up. Of course you need to add the example code i posted inside a $(document).ready(function(){}). post back once you have done these things and let's see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now if only it didn't take super long to load everything...

As for the messy header, If I remove any .js file something different goes wrong with each one

Comment: You are bound to face bigger problems if you load three jQuery versions! It's better if you can remove `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>` and bump up `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>` up the order and then fix any errors that come up.

Comment: Still seems to take impossibly long to load before things are displayed

Comment: Your images amount to a massive 8459 KB!! no wonder it's slow to load. Run your URL through PageSpeed Insights, see if you can address the issues it points out. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Comment: And of course an old problem resurfaces where anything not visible in window on main load shoots to the top when attempted drag is performed hahha

Comment: maybe show a loader? I see two `404` in my console. `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/oddfuture/images/loading.gif"

loading.gif

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/oddfuture/images/close.png"`

Comment: yeah I gotta find where the JS is looking for those images but I set them hidden with .css so that shouldn't be a problem. The loading seems fine, it's just that disappearing act that needs to go. Not sure how I fixed it last time but this time it seemed to start happening again without really touching any essential code that could cause this issue

Comment: I dont quite understand this disappearing act that you are referring to.

Comment: http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/oddfuture/
open this in chrome (maybe safari as well) and try to click and drag any image that you have to scroll down to see
you should see it then

Comment: ok I see it, this maybe a conflict with the two plugins that you are using. We can't have this conversation here as it's getting longer and off topic. I can move this to stackoverflow chat but you need more rep to chat. Can you get your rep up?